# Show user input on new page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a welcome page that collects the user input and I want this information to be shown on other pages as this is a basic jQuery game for a college assessment.

I have tried different ways but I either get undefined appear where I want the userName to be shown, or nothing shows at all, I would preferably like this to show when the page loads on page load.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```js
// let setAvatar = document.getElementById('userAvatar'); //Stores chosen avatar picture for later use
const avatarPics = ["avatar1.png", "avatar2.png", "avatar3.png", "avatar4.png"]; // Array to store avatar images for avatar generator
let randomPic; // This variable will store the index value of the random avatar image in the array for later use
let score = 0;
let userName;
let welcomeUser;

$(document).ready(function() {
  // $('validateInput').validate();

  $('#submit').on('click', setStorage)
  userName = document.getElementById('userName').value;

  if (userName === '') {
    $('.error-message').show();
  } else {
    window.location.href = 'avatar.html';
  }

  function setStorage() {
    let userVal = $('#userName').val();
    localStorage.setItem('userVal', userVal);
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    let getName = localStorage.getItem('userVal');
    $('#welcomeUser').html(getName);
  }

  // function welcomeUser(){
  //     let welcomeUserName = $('#userName').val();
  //     $('#welcomeUser').text('Hi ' + welcomeUserName);
  // }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card bg-transparent border-0" style="width: 25rem; height: 25rem; margin-left: 18%; margin-top: 10%;">
  <div class="card-body text-center d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
    <div class="display-6 mb-2" id="welcomeUser"></div>
    <h1 class="card-title display-6 mb-3 mt-5" id="welcomeUser">Choose Your Avatar</h1>
    <div id="avatar"></div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary me-5" type="button" id="button-addon2 genBtn">Generate Avatar</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button" id="button-addon2 setBtn">Set Avatar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As the information stored in the current page is unloaded when the page is redirected you will need to store it somewhere with some persistence. I'd suggest [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) given your description of the system in the question.

Comment: Thank you, I've had a look at sesssionStorage just there after your reply and It's not doing anything different. I have checked the dev tools and the error is advising that cannot read properties of null (reading 'value'). I have checked and I can't see why this would be the case

Comment: The error is because of this line, `userName = document.getElementById('userName').value;`, not due to local or sessionStorage. the `#userName` element doesn't exist in the DOM, so you can't read a `value` from it

Comment: The HTML page previous to the one above has the input element with the id="userName", so I am really not getting why It is not reading the value

Comment: Because it was in the previous page, not the current one. Every page is its own entity and has no idea about what happened before it, or what will happen after it. You can only interact with the HTML that's currently rendered to the page.

Comment: So will i have to have a separate .js file with the code for my first page that has the user input and then either localStorage it or sessionStorage, then pull this from storage in another .js file for the avatar.html page ?

Comment: That was exactly what I needed to do, thank you for guiding me in the right direction, I now have a separate .js file that gathers, validates and stores the user input, then it loads the avatar.html page which with window.onload it retrieve the stored data and display it, thank you !

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Rory, I managed to research and understand exactly what I was doing wrong, in order to pass the user input to another page, I had t have a separate .js file to gather and store this information with localStorage. Thanks again Rory

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).